# How to embed a WPF web app with nuget packages in a website

Tags: c#, html, .net, wpf, web

I made a C# Windows Form program in Visual Studio. I followed this example [from CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31429/Embedding-a-NET-WinForms-Application-in-an-Interne) to make it web accessible. In short I added a C# WPF Web Application to the solution. The output for the windows form program is changed to class library, and there is a reference to it added to the WPF web app. The end process creates an xbap file you can open in a web browser. The example I referenced also says you can embed the xbap file into an HTML webpage.

The C# program in the example is pretty basic, so I ask what changes do I need to make when using my windows form program?

My windows form program includes the nuget package GhostScript.NET and EPPlus.NET. In addition I added references to System.Office.Excel.Interop, VSTOEE100, VSTOEE90, VBIDE, and a few default references in the .NET framework.

Comment: Starting in February 2009, XBAP applications no longer function when run from the Internet.[3] Attempting to run the XBAP will cause the browser to present a generic error message.[4] An option exists in Internet Explorer 9 that can be used to allow the applications to run,[5] but this must be done with care as it increases the potential attack surface - and there have been security vulnerabilities in XBAP.

Comment: basically means its an out dated tech and new applications shouldn't be built on top of it. Blazor is the replacement for this but its still in design phase

Comment: What is the modern way to embed a windows form into a website?

Comment: There is none. Until Blazor comes out, html + javascript is pretty much your only option

Comment: So, would I be able to just call the windows form from a javascript function. And then combine it with the html?

Comment: nope, you have to use pure html + javascript. Windows form is not an option now, nor will it be one even if Blazor comes out. (with Blazor you still have to use pure html + c#)